# Comparing enums returns error

Tags: ios, swift

I have an enum defined as follows:

```
enum LocationState : Equatable {
    case Idle
    case RetrievingLocation
    case RetrievedLocation(CLLocation)
    case PermissionsDenied(String)
    case LocationUnavailable(NSError)
}
```

I have added the equatable protocol function as follows

```
func == (lhs: LocationState, rhs: LocationState) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}
```

Now I want to determine if a variable that holds an enum is equal to a certain enum:

```
let locationAvailable = locationManager.getCurrentState() != .LocationUnavailable(_)
```

However, this gives the error `'_' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment.`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a value when comparing against enum with associated values.

I would suggest to change the declaration of the enum to following:

```
enum LocationState : Equatable {
    case Idle
    case RetrievingLocation
    case RetrievedLocation(Int)
    case PermissionsDenied(String)
    case LocationUnavailable(NSError?)
}
```

And then you compare in the following way:

```
let locationAvailable = locationManager.getCurrentState() != .LocationUnavailable(nil)
```

In case you want to compare against specific error, you need to pass it as an argument:

```
let locationAvailable = locationManager.getCurrentState() != .LocationUnavailable(myError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace line

```
let locationAvailable = locationManager.getCurrentState() != .LocationUnavailable(_)
```

with

```
let e : NSError!
let locationAvailable = locationManager.getCurrentState() != LocationState.LocationUnavailable(e)
```